# Corda - how to use CollectSignaturesFlow with AnonymousParty

Tags: corda

The `CollectSignaturesFlow` requires a `Collection<FlowSession>` where each `FlowSession` represents the Party you wish to collect a signature from.

You can get a `FlowSession` using `initiateFlow()`, however this requires a `Party`.

How do you collect signatures from `AnonymousParty` instances?

**Context**

Within an issuance flow I have a collection of `CordaX500Name` instances for each participant. I can use these to generate both `Party` and `AnonymousParty` instances - this all works fine!

Now I have an amendment flow where I get the previous state, which contains the original collection of `AnonymousParty` instances. I need to collect signatures from these parties, but as they're anonymous, I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to exchange confidential (i.e. anonymous) identities with the counterparty first as part of the flow. See https://docs.corda.net/api-identity.html and the example CorDapp for confidential identities here: https://www.corda.net/samples/.